# acro list-style=extra-tabular writes over the right margin

Tags: margins, acro

I use the package acro to list my acronyms. The manual describes several *list-styles* where I chose *tabular* as the most interesting one. The problem with this is, that it wastes a bunch of space on the right.

[image: AbkVerz]

The other one is *extra-tabular* which has a bigger width value, unfortunately it writes over the right margin.

```
\documentclass[ngerman,paper=a4]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[only-used=false, list-style=extra-tabular]{acro}

\begin{document}

%%%Abkverzeichnis
\chapter{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}
    \input{abkverz}

\end{document}
```

Anyone knows a solution how to forbid writing over the right margin? I thought about a line-break after the word "Schwächen,".

For some reason `\sloppy` and `\-` has no impact.

```
\DeclareAcronym{swot}{
    short = SWOT, 
    long = {Strenght, Weaknesses, Opportunities, Threats (z. Dt. Stärken, Schwächen, Chancen, Gefahren)}
}

...

\printacronyms[heading=none]  %erstellen des AbkVerz.
```

[image: AbkVerz]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `acro`'s manual section *More on List Customization* the `extra-table` template is described:

> The template `extra-table` typesets the list in a table with four
>   columns: `<short> & <long> & <extra> & <page> \tabularnewline`

In table *Available List Templates and Their Options* you can also read that the default column specification for `extra-table` is `llll` (also that the default table is a `tabular`).

The solution in your case is clear: declare the list style with another column specification. You'll want a `p` column for the long entry, probably also a `p` column for the extra information. You'll need to play with the values a bit to find suiting values for your case. Maybe you also want to change the `tabular` into a `longtable`, too…

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{acro}
\acsetup{
  only-used = false,
  list-style = extra-tabular
}

\DeclareAcroListStyle{extra-tabular}{extra-table}{
  table = tabular ,
  % 4 columns: acronym, description, extra information, page number
  table-spec = lp{.5\linewidth}p{.2\linewidth}l
}

\DeclareAcronym{swot}{
  short = SWOT, 
  long = {Strenght, Weaknesses, Opportunities, Threats (z.\@ Dt.\@ Stärken,
    Schwächen, Chancen, Gefahren)}
}

\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\ac{swot}

\printacronyms

\end{document}
```

Comment: Okay, this is more clear now! Perhaps it's really more reasonable to use the longtable then. I also checked the longtable before, but what I didn't like was that it creates kind of a tab before which also wastes some space... May you know how to remove this also?

Comment: @Eric I don't understand what you mean? Do you mean that `longtable` is centred to the page? This is describes in `longtable`'s manual (and also how to change it)

Comment: @Eric if you don't want any space before the first column inside a table then use `@{}` in the column specification in the beginning.

Comment: Okay, but where do I have to specify this in case of usepackage? I only set list-style=longtable within the options of acro. Do I have to DeclareAcroliststlye as shown by you before?

Comment: Yes, in `\DeclareAcroListStyle`. Use `table = longtable` there, and maybe `table-spec = @{}lp{.5\linewidth}p{.2\linewidth}l@{}`. (`\setlength\LTleft{0pt}` will move `longtable` to the left of the page…)

Comment: sorry, what to do with the `\setlength\LTleft{0pt}`? below `table-spec`?

Comment: @Eric have a look at `longtable`'s manual. The length `\LTleft` is inserted to the left of a `longtable` which is the reason a `longtable` does not align with the margin to the left. If you set this length to zero the longtable will align to the margin. Just put it in your preamble after loading `longtable`.